# phpmyadmin insert a column underneath a column

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am creating a seach form.
I want a user to be able to choose some kind of yarn, then some kind of wool, then some colour and then a number of balls of yarn.
For that I am trying to set up a database in phpmyadmin with columns within columns within columns but I am failing!

For now I have a database named "yarn". In that database I have a table named "wool". In that table I have some columns of different types of wool (sheep, goat, etc.).
How can I set up columns within columns and so on???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to create different tables for each. These attributes then can reference others through Foreign Keys
You could then have tables:
**Yarn**,
**WoolType**,
**Color**,

Each table will have respected colums, for example:
**Yarn**

- YarnId
- WoolTypeId
- ColorId
- Length/Units (Available on stock?)

**Color**

- ColorId
- Color

**WoolType**

- WoolTypeId
- WoolType

Great study material can be found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

I don't think you can have columns within columns at least not in the traditional database